# ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

I am using this code to train news article dataset.

https://github.com/borislavmavrin/stance-detection/blob/master/model_matchingLSTM_wdev.py

When I load GoogleNews word2vec file, it gives me error.

> ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.

The stacktrace starts from line https://github.com/borislavmavrin/stance-detection/blob/master/model_matchingLSTM_wdev.py#L614,

and then goes to https://github.com/borislavmavrin/stance-detection/blob/master/model_matchingLSTM_wdev.py#L154

Any help here would be appreciated. I don't want to change the structure of this code right now, I am just focused more on results for now as this is just a prototype I want to do on this dataset. If the results are good enough, I might write my own model or improve the existing one.

Comment: Are you using a GPU? How large is your RAM? One option might be to use the `with tf.device("cpu:0"):` clause to nest the part that initializes the word embeddings.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the computation on CPU will not help. The issue here is that `tf.constant`'s implementation involves serializing the value using protocol buffers. The latter has a size constraint of at most 2GB.

One workaround is to replace the constant with a placeholder and feed the value in `sess.run()`.

Another option you can try is breaking up the constant into a few constants (split your numpy array and create a `tf.constant` for each part) and concatenating them using `tf.concat`. This can be done locally, without the need to feed the placeholder later.